# Raw SQL for Query

Tags: postgresql, join

I am trying to query my Database using raw SQL. I want to get objects with a like on a certain field. I also want to query these objects location relation for a certain field. This is the SQL I have so far:

```
Center.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM Centers WHERE name ILIKE '%" + query + "%'
                    AND status = 1");
```

A center has a location relation and I want query the location field also. Location.country = something? The database I am using is a PostgreSQL db and I am using Datamapper as an ORM. I had this query setup using datamapper but the results were not good. Can anyone help me extend this query to include a query on the `Center.location`'s country field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a field in each table so SQL knows how to join the correct records. I am going to use .ID in the example but this needs to be changed to whatever field you may use (ID, SSN, TIN, ACCT, etc.) that can join the two tables.

You should swap out the .* for actual columns you need, like
`SELECT Centers.name, Centers.status, Location.country`

```
SELECT Centers.*, Location.country
  FROM Centers
  INNER JOIN Location
  ON Centers.ID = Location.ID
  WHERE Centers.name LIKE '%query%'
  AND Centers.status = 1
  AND Location.country LIKE '%something%'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show a brief model of the database in question?

I would assume from  "A center has a location relation and I want query the location field also. Location.country = something" that there is another table you're looking to **Join** with.

Your query should define the columns being returned (swap the star out for the column headings, and maybe prefix them with the table names.)

Look here for more information on Joins.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You would [`JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) table `location` to table `centers` for that.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   centers  c
JOIN   location l ON l.location_id = c.location_id
WHERE  c.name ILIKE '%query%'
AND    c.status = 1
AND    l.country = 'something'
```

Assuming you have a 1:n relationship between `location` and `centers` that is implemented with a foreign key column `location_id`.

Use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Centersc c
JOIN Locations l ON l.id = c.location_id
WHERE c.name ILIKE ?
AND c.status = 1
AND l.country = ?
```

Note that I have removed all application code from the answer because this is solely an SQL question.